# Почему не работает Jinja2 на хостинге?

Tags: html, css, flask, hosting, jinja2

1. Здравствуйте, почему не работает Jinja2 на хотсинге? {% extends "base.html" %} {% block content %} просто отображаются на странице как текст. В чем проблема? хостинг: reg.ru - ispmanager
2. Как лучше организовать свои файлы? Ведь html должны хранится в папке templates, но index.html не читается оттуда.

Comment: А почему вы решили, что Jinja2 должен работать? Как установили, как подключили?

Comment: установил на хостинг через pip необходимые пакеты, дальше не знаю что делать, да и гайдов не нашел, если у вас есть необходимый материал, то скиньте, пожалуйста

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/deploying/index.html

Comment: я не понимаю, я на сервере установил питон, в нем поставил flask, сам фласк то работает, но шаблонизатор почему-то нет, как его отдельно то туда ставить?

Comment: Как вы проверили, что фласк работает?

Comment: щас сидел тестил, создал простой html файл и в py через return render_template(example.html) вывелась страница